# Find the elements of Aut $(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ 1 \})$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, automorphism-group

I would like to see if my answer to this problem is correct or if there are some missing parts.

Automorphism in my textbook means biholomorphism between same domains. i.e $f \in \text{Aut}\left ( \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \right) = \{f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} : f \text{ is biholomorphism} \}$.

First, let $f\in \text{Aut}\left ( \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \right )$ be arbitrarily chosen.
Letting $g(z)=f(z+1)-1$, we can see that $g\in \text{Aut}\left ( \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \right )$.

By the Theorem which tells us "$g\in \text{Aut}\left ( \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \right ) \Leftrightarrow \exists a\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ s.t either $g(z)=az$ or $g(z)=\frac{1}{az}$," we get $f(z+1)=g(z)+1$ so that $f(z+1)=az+1$ or $f(z+1)=\frac{1}{az}+1$.

This implies that either $f(z)=az-a+1$ or $f(z)=\frac{1}{a(z-1)}+1$.

Hence, every element in $\text{Aut}\left ( \mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\} \right )$ has to be in the form of $az-a+1$ or $\frac{1}{a(z-1)}+1$ with $a \neq 0$.

Any help finding flaws in my solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is your $\operatorname{Aut}$ the group of all invertible holomorphic maps from a set to itself. If so then please edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks for reminding me that. Yes, it refers to biholomorphism between same domains.

Comment: The more interesting part is that the automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ are exactly the functions of the form $g(z)=az$ or $g(z) = 1/(az)$. If you can use that as a given theorem  then your answer is correct.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your answer!